# Express least and greatest fixed point using predicate and quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Let $f$ be a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. A fixed point of $f$ is an element $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x) = x$. A least fixed point of $f$ is the smallest number $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x) = x$. A greatest fixed point of $f$ is the largest number $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x) = x$.

1. Express using the language of predicate logic the English statement: “$f$ has a least fixed point”. You may use the predefined function $f$ as well as the predefined predicates $=$ and $<$.
2. Express using the language of predicate logic the English statement: “$f$ has a greatest fixed point”. You may use the predefined function $f$ as well as the predefined predicates $=$ and $<$.

My attempt for 1 is $\exists x \forall y (x < y \ \&\  f(x)=x)$. I am not sure how I would start 2 with only $<$ and $=$.

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)

Answer (score 1):

Look again. Your $\exists x\forall y(x < y \text{ and } f(x)=x)$ says: there is a number $x$ which is smaller than every number $y$ and which is a fixed point of $f$ ... which is not what you wanted at all!

(1) says that there is a fixed point for $f$ such that any other fixed point is larger than it. So as a half-way Loglish rendition you want

> $(\exists x)(x \text{ is fixed point } \land (\forall y)(y \text{ is fixed point } \to y \text{ greater than or equal to } x))$

which then becomes

> $(\exists x)(fx = x \land (\forall y)(fy = y \to (x = y \lor x <y))$

or equivalently (why?)

> $(\exists x)(fx = x \land (\forall y)((fy = y \land \neg x = y) \to x <y))$

With that model to follow, now do (2) in two similar steps (remembering that a fixed point is the greatest one if no number bigger than it is a fixed point).

Comment: Thank you so much, I always get confused on the placement of these quantifiers!

Comment: Welcome to math.se! (And remember to vote-up/accept answers you find helpful as a guide to others.)